# Is it possible to use the "call" or "apply" to pass the an array of arguments to multiple functions at once?

Tags: javascript, function, call, apply

For example, let's say I have two functions, `a` and `b`, and both `a` and `b` take a two `string` arguments and then log these strings to the console:

```
function a(w, x) {
  console.log(w, x);
}

function b(y, z) {
  console.log(y, z);
}
```

Is it possible to call `a` **and** `b` using `call` or `apply` to pass an array of arguments to both functions at once?

For example, here is some pseudo code:

```
(a, b).apply(window, ["Wello", "Horld"]);
```

Is it possible to achieve this without using loops or doing something this:

```
var args = ["Wello", "Horld"];
a.apply(window, args);
b.apply(window, args);
```

Also, would it be possible to call more than two functions at once?

**NOTE:** the functions can run in any order.

Thanks.

Comment: JavaScript has just one thread of execution. It doesn't make sense to think about two functions running "at the same time".

Comment: @Pointy only if they are not async.

Comment: @Lux ?? That does not matter.

Comment: So you're asking whether there's some way to start the execution of a *sequence* of function calls? To me "at once" means "at the same time".

Comment: @Pointy 2 async functions may be in execution at the same time. Sure no 2 JS statements can be parallel, but if one function is awaiting the other can run, in the end meaning both are active at the same time. The definition of cooperative multitasking.

Comment: @Lux at any given point in time, only one function will actually be running.  It depends on what one means by "running" or "active" I suppose; a generator function that is in-between a `yield` and a `.next()` doesn't seem very active to me, any more than a button click handler while nobody's touching the mouse.

Comment: Active as in "the callstack does exist". True multi threading is always limited to the CPU, but in practice it doesn't make a difference. And from the thinking model perspective async functions may run in parallel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to call a and b using call or apply to pass an array of arguments to both functions at once?
>
> ...
>
> Is it possible to achieve this without using loops or doing something this...

No. You have to do what you've described, either putting the arguments in an array and making each call, or looping through an array of functions, etc.

For instance:

```
for (const f of [a, b]) {
    f.apply(window, ["Wello", "Horld"]);
    // Or if you have the arguments as discrete things like that, I'd use call:
    //f.call(window, "Wello", "Horld");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could still need some iteration for the functions, by taking the functions into an array and call them with [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

```js
function a(w, x) {
    console.log(w, x);
}

function b(y, z) {
    console.log(y, z);
}

[a, b].forEach(fn => fn.apply(window, ["Wello", "Horld"]));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some kind of loop.

```
const args = ["Wello", "Horld"];
[a, b].forEach(f => f.apply(Windows, args));
```

Will do the trick. This works for as much functions as you want.